# How to Match Days, Families, Streets, and Activities in a Complex Logic Puzzle in CLIPS IDE

Tags: clips

Please help me

This is a complex logic puzzle where we need to figure out Uncle Józsi's seven daily activities, taking into account the information provided in various instructions and hints.

This is a complex logic puzzle where we need to figure out Uncle Józsi's seven daily activities, taking into account the information provided in various instructions and hints.

Before we get started, let's look at the kind of information we're searching for:

Day: Monday through Friday (5 days)

Families: Pászti, Déri, Fehér, Berkes, Kardos (5 families)

Street: Telepi Street, Málna Street, Jenei Street, Rózsika Street, Bukta Street (5 streets)

Activities: spring spraying, washing machine repair, fence painting, TV antenna adjustment, gutter cleaning (5 activities)

Based on the information, we know the following:

```
Uncle Józsi did not do the spring spraying on Telepi Street. (The name of the family is longer than that of the family living on Málna Street.)

The Pászti family does not live on Jenei Street, and they called Uncle Józsi on Wednesday.

The Déri family lives on Rózsika Street, but Uncle Józsi did not work for them on Monday.

One day, the Fehér family entrusted him with something, and the next day he was painting a fence.

On Monday, he repaired a washing machine.

He worked on Bukta Street two days later than at the Berkes family, where he adjusted the TV antenna.

He did not do the gutter cleaning at the Kardos family.
```

You gave rules for trying to solve a logic puzzle where there are several families, streets, tasks, and days, and they have to be matched according to certain rules. Your rules are specific and create a relationship between the variables. This code needs to be written in the CLIPS IDE, The program should solve the puzzle during the trials and print it out in a table.

I have updated the task and provided the code that I wrote. However, the code outputs the answer that is not quite correct. Some of the rules are not working correctly.

```
(deffacts starting-facts
    (day "Monday") (day "Tuesday") (day "Wednesday") (day "Thursday") (day "Friday")
    (family "Pászti") (family "Déri") (family "Fehér") (family "Berkes") (family "Kardos")
    (street "Telepi") (street "Málna") (street "Jenei") (street "Rózsika") (street "Bukta")
    (activity "Spring spraying") (activity "Washing machine repair") (activity "Fence painting") 
    (activity "TV antenna adjustment") (activity "Gutter cleaning")
)

(defrule rule1
    ?f1 <- (day ?d) 
    ?f2 <- (family ?f) 
    ?f3 <- (street ?s) 
    ?f4 <- (activity "Spring spraying")
    (test (neq ?s "Telepi")) 
=>
    (assert (activity ?f ?s ?d "Spring spraying"))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule rule2
    ?f1 <- (family "Pászti") 
    ?f2 <- (day "Wednesday")
    ?f3 <- (street ?s)
    ?f4 <- (activity ?a)
    (test (neq ?s "Jenei"))
=>
    (assert (activity "Pászti" ?s "Wednesday" ?a))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule rule3
    ?f1 <- (family "Déri") 
    ?f2 <- (street "Rózsika")
    ?f3 <- (day ?d)
    ?f4 <- (activity ?a)
    (test (neq ?d "Monday"))
=>
    (assert (activity "Déri" "Rózsika" ?d ?a))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule rule4
    ?f1 <- (family "Fehér") 
    ?f2 <- (street ?s)
    ?f3 <- (day ?d)
    ?f4 <- (activity ?a)
    (test (neq ?a "Fence painting"))
=>
    (assert (activity "Fehér" ?s ?d ?a))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule rule5
    ?f1 <- (day "Monday")
    ?f2 <- (activity "Washing machine repair")
    ?f3 <- (family ?f)
    ?f4 <- (street ?s)
=>
    (assert (activity ?f ?s "Monday" "Washing machine repair"))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule rule6
    ?f1 <- (family "Berkes") 
    ?f2 <- (activity "TV antenna adjustment")
    ?f3 <- (day ?d)
    ?f4 <- (street ?s)
    (test (neq ?s "Bukta"))
=>
    (assert (activity "Berkes" ?s ?d "TV antenna adjustment"))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule rule7
    ?f1 <- (family "Kardos") 
    ?f2 <- (street ?s)
    ?f3 <- (day ?d)
    ?f4 <- (activity ?a)
    (test (neq ?a "Gutter cleaning"))
=>
    (assert (activity "Kardos" ?s ?d ?a))
    (retract ?f1 ?f2 ?f3 ?f4)
)

(defrule print-result
    ?f <- (activity ?f ?s ?d ?a)
=>
    (printout t "On " ?d ", Uncle Józsi worked with the " ?f " family, at " ?s " street, where he carried out the following activity: " ?a crlf)
    (retract ?f)
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving a complex logic puzzle with CLIPS IDE and specific rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368001/solving-a-complex-logic-puzzle-with-clips-ide-and-specific-rules)